# How to output Mathematica Lists as a Table to a file?

Tags: output-formatting, files-and-directories

Given the following List:

```
  lis =  { {-2.8336, -1.1088, -0.1232, 1.23493}, {-2.8336, -1.1088, 0.1232, 
      1.08433}, {-2.8336, -0.8624, -0.616, 
      1.04417}, {-2.8336, -0.8624, -0.3696, 
      1.10441}, {-2.8336, -0.8624, -0.1232, 1.17469}, {-2.8336, -0.8624, 
      0.1232, 1.09437}, {-2.8336, -0.8624, 0.3696, 
      1.43574}, {-2.8336, -0.8624, 0.616, 
      1.07429}, {-2.8336, -0.616, -0.8624, 
      1.26506}, {-2.8336, -0.616, -0.616, 1.43574} }
```

One can convert it to a table as follows: `lis//TableForm`

But that just works for displaying it in *Mathematica*. How can one easily save that list to a text file so that it appears as a table?

Comment: To me, a table is more than a string of text, for example, of ASCII characters. It implies some sort of structure or formatting.  For what applications would you like the output to appear as a table?

Comment: This was pretty obvious from looking up `Export` in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this will work for you, but you might try something simple such as

```
data = {
  {-2.8336, -1.1088, -0.1232, 1.23493},
  {-2.8336, -1.1088, 0.1232, 1.08433},
  {-2.8336, -0.8624, -0.616, 1.04417},
  {-2.8336, -0.8624, -0.3696, 1.10441},
  {-2.8336, -0.8624, -0.1232, 1.17469}, 
  {-2.8336, -0.8624, 0.1232, 1.09437}, 
  {-2.8336, -0.8624, 0.3696, 1.43574}, 
  {-2.8336, -0.8624, 0.616, 1.07429}, 
  {-2.8336, -0.616, -0.8624, 1.26506}, 
  {-2.8336, -0.616, -0.616, 1.43574}
};

Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "test.csv"}], data]
```

This produces a file with the following content:

-2.8336,-1.1088,-0.1232,1.23493
-2.8336,-1.1088,0.1232,1.08433
-2.8336,-0.8624,-0.616,1.04417
-2.8336,-0.8624,-0.3696,1.10441
-2.8336,-0.8624,-0.1232,1.17469
-2.8336,-0.8624,0.1232,1.09437
-2.8336,-0.8624,0.3696,1.43574
-2.8336,-0.8624,0.616,1.07429
-2.8336,-0.616,-0.8624,1.26506
-2.8336,-0.616,-0.616,1.43574

Answer (score 6):

A quick look at the documentation for [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html) reveals that *Mathematica* supports a range of [Export formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24ExportFormats.html)  and that there is a [guide on how to import and export data in different formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html).

In that guide it states:

> `Export["file", list, "Table"]` writes out data separated by spaces, with numbers given in C or Fortran-like form, as in `2.3E5` and so on.

[This documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingFiles.html) might also be useful.

Comment: And add [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19387/how-to-export-data-files-using-specific-format) for formatting problems.