# How to export a table in with reals given in e-notation?

Tags: export

```
ttt=Table[(i + j) 10^(-30), {i, 1}, {j, 2}];
Export["test.dat", ttt, "Table"]
```

This gives notation`1/500000000000000000000000000000`, but I need 2.0000e-30 or similar in the file (i.e, Fortran-readable).

Somewhere I probably need to use `FortranForm`, `NumberFormat`, `ExponentFunction`, or some other coercion, but I cannot find it in any of the existing discussions on the web (I do see answers but none of them actually works!)

Comment: After some trying, it seems that the actual (short) answer is to use N[ttt] :

    ttt=Table[(i+j) 10^(-30), {i, 1}, {j, 2}]; Export["test.dat", N[ttt] , "Table"]

So unless I overlooked something, this seems to be the most basic way of writing a Fortran-readable table.

Comment: Take a look a some of the answers to [How to export data files using specific format](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19387/how-to-export-data-files-using-specific-format)

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question.  See also http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html

Comment: No it is not a duplicate of the discussion "How to export data files using specific format" because there, the solution using N[ ] is not even mentioned!
That was exactly my problem: all earlier discussions seemed to veer off into obfuscated work-arounds. But the solution now that I found it, is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Use `N[ttt]` so it becomes:

```
ttt=Table[(i+j) 10^(-30), {i, 1}, {j, 2}];
Export["test.dat", N[ttt] , "Table"]
```