# NumberForm with fixed width and exponent as "e+00" or "e-02"

Tags: number-representation, output-formatting

I wish to export a matrix of real numbers `out` to a txt file in which the entries have the MatLab form:

```
7.568627450980391913e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00
3.176470588235293935e-01
```

Code `Export["out.txt", ScientificForm[out,19,NumberFormat->(Row[{#1,"e",#3}]&)], "Table"];` doesn't do what I want. How can I remedy this?

Comment: [probable duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19387/5467)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `andre314` for providing the link and `avni` for the code in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19387/how-to-export-data-files-using-specific-number-format), the solution is:

```
Eform[x_?NumericQ,d_:18]:=Module[{m,e,mm,ee}, {m,e}=MantissaExponent[x+0.0];m=m*10; 
If[m!=0,e=e-1,m=0.]; e=Clip[e,{-99,99}]; mm=ToString[PaddedForm[m,{d+1,d}]]; 
ee=If[-10<e<10,"0",""]<>ToString[Abs@e]; StringJoin[mm,If[e<0,"e-","e+"],ee]];

Export["out.txt",Map[Eform,out,{2}],"Table","FieldSeparators"->""];
```

(I thought there would be an easier, i.e. already built-in function for this, that's why I asked.)

Comment: Carl Woll’s answer is much simpler and probably faster. I’d give that one a try too.