# Exporting a table using Fortran format for numbers

Tags: export, fortran

I would like to export in txt or tsv format a table that contains both alphameric and numeric entries, but I would like the numeric entries to be exported in Fortran format.

For example 1.234E-9.

Is there a convenient way to to this, or must I build strings?

Comment: There is an actual `FortranForm` function. Didn't check to see what happens if you export a `FortranForm` expression directly, but if the `FortranForm` head comes through, then you would just use `ToString` to clean that up. Or maybe some `Export` option.

Comment: I have found that exporting to a file using TSV format works for this. To avoid quotes on text I used TextDelimiters -> “”.  I could not find a way to set the threshold at which numbers were expressed in E notation. 
I would like to see Wolfram put more effort into formatting material intended to be read by other programs. 
I did not find the earlier answers useful.

Answer (score 1):

This was based on one of the answers from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19387/how-to-export-data-files-using-specific-number-format?rq=1)

```
ClearAll[FortranReal] ;
SetAttributes[FortranReal, Listable] ;
FortranReal[
number_Real,
precision_Integer: Ceiling[$MachinePrecision] + 1 ,
kind_String: ""
] := Block[
  {mantissa, exponent, sign},
  {mantissa,exponent} = If[SameQ[number,N[0,Precision[number]]],List[N[0,Precision[number]],1],MantissaExponent[number]] ;
  mantissa = N[Times[10,mantissa],precision] ;
  mantissa = NumberForm[mantissa,Rule[DefaultPrintPrecision,precision]] ;
  exponent = Subtract[exponent,1] ;
  sign = Sign[exponent] ;
  sign = Which[GreaterEqual[sign,0],"+",Less[sign,0],"-"] ;
  exponent = Abs[exponent] ;
  mantissa = ToString[mantissa] ;
  mantissa =  StringTrim[mantissa,"0"..] ;
  mantissa = If[SameQ[mantissa,"."],"0.",mantissa] ;
  If[UnsameQ[exponent,0],StringTemplate["`1`E`2``3``4`"][mantissa,sign,exponent,kind],StringTemplate["`1``2`"][mantissa, kind]]
] ;
```

Examples:

```
FortranReal[100.0*Pi]
FortranReal[{0.1*N[E], N[E], 10*N[E]}]
FortranReal[{0.1*N[E], N[E], 10*N[E]}, 3]
FortranReal[{0.1*N[E], N[E], 10*N[E]},Ceiling[$MachinePrecision] + 1 , "_REAL64" ]
(* "3.141592653589793E+2" *)
(* {"2.7182818284590455E-1","2.7182818284590446","2.7182818284590446E+1"} *)
(* {"2.72E-1","2.72","2.72E+1"} *)
(* {"2.7182818284590455E-1_REAL64","2.7182818284590446_REAL64","2.7182818284590446E+1_REAL64"} *)
```